# How can I update other documents in FIrestore based on updating another?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

So I want to update multiple documents in my 'appointments' collection based on a document being updated in the 'customer' collection. How can I achieve this through firebase functions? I feel like my code is legit, but the other docs aren't updating.
Below is my code.
Any help is much appreciated!!!

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)


exports.customerStatusUpdated = functions.firestore
.document('customers/{customerId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const customer = context.params.appointmentId;
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const previousValue = change.before.data();
    const newStatus = newValue.accountStatus;
    const prevStatus = previousValue.accountStatus;
    const clientUID = previousValue.userId;
    let promises = []
    if(newValue !== prevStatus){
        admin.firestore().collection('appointments').where('clientUID', '==', `${clientUID}`)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const id = doc.id
                const p = admin.firestore().collection('appointments').doc(id).update({clientStatus: newStatus})
                promises.push(p)
            });
            return Promise.all(promises)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });

    }
})
```

**UPDATE:** There was somehow a variable declared at the top of my code that was causing me not to be able to update by Firebase Functions

This code works! Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Try adding a `return` before ` admin.firestore()` in the `if (newValue !== prevStatus)` block

Comment: @Dharmaraj The code works actually lol..  There was somehow a variable declared at the top of my code that was causing me not to be able to update by Firebase Functions